# how do djangos field instances work in models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Something I'm confused about in Django is how the model's fields work.

You define them as class variables.

So, a class like this:

```
class Foo:
    avar = "something here"
```

And if you created two instances.

```
f1 = Foo()
f2 = Foo()
```

And you set avar to be something else, this would affect both instances of `Foo`. So, how does django keep the models field values between instances correct? Does it simply use the base class variables to create the tables, and then query the database for the model / table to return the correct field values for respective instances?

Or, does it do something at the metaclass level to defer creation, until say the models `__init__` / `__new__` and then create unique instances of the fields?

Going further... for something like `amodel = AModel.objects.get(*)` I could see how Django would hit the database and then perhaps return an instance of the model class with the column values filled in for the fields so you could access the attribute `amodel.field` for the value correctly. This would make sense, but I'm not sure I understand how the internals of this work.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. You've created two separate model instances. They are separate objects with separate properties and (if you were to save them) separate rows in the database.

Comment: If you want to know how the `models.Model` internals work, you can lookup the code in `path/to/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py` see `class Model`.

Comment: @solarissmoke what OP has are *class* attributes rather than *instance* attributes. Since the object is a string, it doesn't really matter: assigning to `avar` will rebind the name to a local variable instead of changing the class attribute. However, if `avar` was something mutable, this would an important distinction. So, fluffy_muffin: I don't think setting `avar` will affect both objects. Unless you set `Foo.avar`, but why would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django uses a [metaclass](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ba53da894fc713629ae4d3fbdd14eff98c808389/django/db/models/base.py#L78) to gather all fields, and collects them in `Model._meta`. After the class is created, fields are no longer part of the model class itself:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=255)

>>> Foo.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    Foo.bar
AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'bar'
```

Some field types (e.g. `ForeignKey`) use a descriptor, which will be a class attribute, but this is not the field itself.

When a model is instantiated, `__init__` will [loop through](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ba53da894fc713629ae4d3fbdd14eff98c808389/django/db/models/base.py#L494) all fields in `self._meta`, and assign a default value (usually `None` if you provide no field default) to the instance. This ensures that a value exists for each field, that the value is an instance variable, and that it can be any Python object.

All model methods use the information in `Foo._meta` to determine which attributes should be treated as fields, and which are just regular attributes.

Also note that when you override a class variable on an instance, what actually happens is that the class variable is shadowed by the instance variable. If you change the variable on the class itself, any instance that does not have an instance variable will have the value changed as well. If you delete the variable on the instance, the value will revert back to the (current) class variable's value:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     bar = 'test'
...
>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> f2 = Foo()
>>> f1.bar = 'shadowed'
>>> Foo.bar = 'changed'
>>> f1.bar
'shadowed'
>>> f2.bar
'changed'
>>> del f1.bar
>>> f1.bar
'changed'
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular class variable is a property of the class. It is not stored in the database (only [model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/) are). In your case, `avar` is not a model field. It is just a simple python class variable.

If you change the class variable on an instance of `Foo`, it will only affect that instance. All other instances will not be affected. Proof:

```
class Foo:
    avar = 'Something'

a = Foo()
b = Foo()

a.avar = 'Something else'

print a.avar
> 'Something else'

print b.avar
> 'Something'
```

Note that changing `avar` on `a` does not alter it on `b`. Note also that the changed value of `a.avar` will only exist as long as `a` itself exists. This property is not stored in the database and if you load a new object from the database it will just have the default `avar` of the class.

Comment: Okay I completely misunderstood how class variables worked then. This makes more sense.

Comment: Although this answer explains how *class variables work*, it does not answer the original question *how do Django field instances work in models*. See [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278141/how-do-djangos-field-instances-work-in-models#answer-38280621)

Answer (score 0):

A few things are going on here. First, all you are doing is creating a string in your Foo object just like any other python object. If you want it to be a field in the database, you need to use a type from models. Something like

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    avar = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Later on, if you want to make some changes to a model, make your changes, then call the save() method to update the record in the database.

```
f1.avar = "Something New"
f1.save()
```

Comment: avar was just a placeholder. I was trying to highlight the issue between regular class variable vs how django might potentially handle them. I think your answer actually highlights my question further. You set `f1.avar` to "Something New" but say you went to save `f2` then you just set `f2`'s `avar` to "Something New" as well. Or theoretically at least, with how the code in the question would work. Hence my confusion / question about how Django's class variables of field instances work.